# keyframe animation not working properly - CSS

Tags: html, css, angular

I have an angular component that has a button and the button triggers a sidePanel and the side panels slidesOut over the component that has the button triggering the side panel to come out. I have 2 issues I can solve. The side panel has a `width of 350px;`

1) When the component with the button is loaded you can see the sidePanel doing the animation to hide

2) The slideIn works fine but the slideOut moves really fast

**HTML**

```
<div class="credit-card-container {{toggleSideBarFlag ? 'showSideBar': 'hideSideBar'}} {{ submittingPayment ? 'payment-success-container' : ''}}">
    <app-bulk-pay-credit-card [ccTotalDue]="totalDue" [pickupAvailabilityList]='selectedEquipment' (submittingPayment)="isSubmittingPayment(true)"
      (toggleSideBar)="onToggleSideBar(false)" (close)="onCloseBulkPay(false)"></app-bulk-pay-credit-card>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .bulk-pay-storage-container {
        .showSideBar {
          width: 100%;
          display: block;
          position: absolute;
          z-index: 9999;
          animation: slideIn 1s;
        }

        .hideSideBar {
          width: 100%;
          display: block;
          position: absolute;
          right: -350px;
          z-index: 9999;
          animation: slideOut 1s forwards;
        }
      }

@keyframes slideIn {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(350px);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translate(0);
  }
}

@keyframes slideOut {
  100% {
    transform: translateX(350px);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `transitions` rather than `animations` in your example.
You can basically toggle between having `showSideBar` class and not having it.
Sidebar's start position is hidden outside of the viewport (`left: -350px`) and its visible state is `left: 0`.

Set `left` and `transition` properties on your sidebar and remove the `animation` property.

```
.bulk-pay-storage-container {
  / ... /
  left: -350px;
  transition: left 2s;
}

.bulk-pay-storage-container.showSideBar {
  left: 0
}
```